# Reshaping the result of a pd.DataFrame.aggregate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with 2 numeric columns

```
DATA_ROWS = 5
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1]*DATA_ROWS,"x":[1,2,3,4,5],
                        "z":[1,1,1,5,6]})
df.set_index("id", drop=True, append=True, inplace=True)

          x  z
     id      
   0   1  1  1
   1   1  2  1
   2   1  3  1
   3   1  4  5
   4   1  5  6
```

(`id` is an index)

Also, I have a list of functions

```
funcs = [np.max, np.min, np.std, func1, func2]
```

So, when I aggregate, I got

```
df.aggregate(funcs)

                                                           x         z
amax                                                5.000000  6.000000
amin                                                1.000000  1.000000
std                                                 1.581139  2.489980
func1                                               7.000000  1.000000
func2                                              23.500000  6.200000
```

I will like to get instead of this the following

```
   x_amax, x_amin  x_std  x_func1 x_func2 z_amax z_amin z_std z_func1 z_func2
1  5.000   1.000 1.5811    7.000  23.500  6.000  1.000 2.4899 1.000  6.2000
```

I read the documentaion about `pivot`, `melt` etc and I can't get how to do this, Any ideas?

Comment: How can this data be reproduced? You have provided some dummy data and some esoteric functions `func1` and `func2`, so how can we know to reproduce your data?

Comment: Added code for creating the data frame. The functions `func1` and `func2`  are aggregation functions that return numbers.

Comment: Thanks for that, but my question was how to reproduce the output of df.aggregate given we don't know your custom function definitions?

Comment: I think you should be using groupby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape, [`to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) for one column `df` and then transpose by [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html). Last create `columns` by flattening `MultiIndex` by `map` and `join`:

```
#select first value of level id
id1 = df_fdw.index.get_level_values('id')[0]

df = df.unstack().to_frame(id1).T
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
   x_amax  x_amin     x_std  x_func1  x_func2  z_amax  z_amin    z_std  \
1     5.0     1.0  1.581139      3.0     15.0     6.0     1.0  2.48998   

   z_func1  z_func2  
1      2.8     14.0
```

Solution for `multiple` id (working nice for unique `id` too):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[1]*2 + [2]*3,"x":[1,2,3,4,5],
                        "z":[1,1,1,5,6]})
df.set_index("id", drop=True, append=True, inplace=True)

#sample functions
def func1(x):
    return x.mean()

def func2(x):
    return x.sum()


funcs = [np.max, np.min, np.std, func1, func2]

df = df.groupby(level='id').aggregate(funcs)
df.columns = df.columns.map('_'.join)
print (df)
    x_amax  x_amin     x_std  x_func1  x_func2  z_amax  z_amin     z_std  \
id                                                                         
1        2       1  0.707107      1.5        3       1       1  0.000000   
2        5       3  1.000000      4.0       12       6       1  2.645751   

    z_func1  z_func2  
id                    
1         1        2  
2         4       12
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick answer! But I made a mistake in the question: I want that the index be the `id` value not the string `id` (I already fix that in the question). I apologize for that mistake

Comment: What is `print (df.index)` ? `id` is level of `MultiIndex` or column?

Comment: `print(df.index)` is
```MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1]],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]],
           names=[None, 'id'])
```

Comment: Thank you! If that column contains more `id` values, the way to go is using `groupby` and then your code, right?

Comment: Then it is a bit complicated, I add answer for it too. Give me a minute.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be using `groupby` here, if you want a row per `id`.

```
df1 = df.groupby('id').agg([np.max, np.min, np.std, 'first', 'last'])
df1.columns =['_'.join(c) for c in df1.columns.values]

df1

    x_amax  x_amin     x_std  x_first  x_last  z_amax  z_amin    z_std  \
id                                                                       
1        5       1  1.581139        1       5       6       1  2.48998   

    z_first  z_last  
id                   
1         1       6
```

Note that you can pass string names of all the basic aggregation functions (mean/max/min/std/etc) to `agg`, so this works too:

```
aggfuncs = ['max', 'min', 'std', func1, func2]
df1 = df.groupby('id').agg(aggfuncs)
```